# Ziparchive extracto function treats the second parameter as folder

Tags: php, extract, php-ziparchive

I tried to extract a zip file using **ziparchive**, here's my code:

```
$path = "/test/admin";
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open("test.zip") === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo($path."/", array("index.php"));
    $zip->close();
}
```

but the output becomes /test/admin/index.php/.
The file becomes a folder.

Can someone help me with this.

Comment: You are missing a quotemark at the end of index.php for a start - you might want to change that first.

Comment: What if you extract the zip with other tools?

Comment: what other tools specifically?